# Out of memory error in composer when requiring drupal/bootstrap

Tags: 8, composer

I currently set up a Drupal 8 website using Composer like described [here](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/goodbye-drush-make-hello-composer).
Drupal is already running. Now I want to add Bootstrap theme by calling

```
composer require drupal/bootstrap
```

But I get

> Using version ^7.3 for drupal/bootstrap
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
>
> mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
>   PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 515907584) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php on line 221
>
> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 515907584) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php on line 221

Im using Composer version 1.2.1 2016-09-12 11:27:19

Comment: This is off-topic because composer usage is a general PHP topic. The issue has to do with the memory usage of `composer update`, which per the composer maintainer's words should only be used on non-production systems. This is really annoying and limiting for me personally because I like to run a build process on jenkins and this makes the jenkins build agent require some ridiculous amount of memory (> 1gb) to do `composer update`. This could be on-topic if the question asked about how to store composer.install for a Drupal site without using composer from scratch.

Comment: See Saldaek's last comment in https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5082.

Comment: @mradcliffe I think this can count as on topic, since this is directly related to using composer on a Drupal site, to install (download) a new module.

Comment: I tried to remove composer.lock and then `composer install`, but even then it doesn't install. So, I think, this is not alone a problem with the `update` command, but with `install` as well

Comment: In some cases I have had the memory limit issue when using PHP 5.6 and then after switching to PHP 7.1 everything ran correctly with the same memory limit.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to your `php.ini` file's `memory_limit` entry which defaults to `128M`. **You need access to your server's `php` configuration file**. If you do here is the step by step for making that change on an Ubuntu server with **PHP 7** and **PHP CLI** extension.

1. Open the PHP CLI configuration file located at `/etc/php/7.0/cli`; e.g. I use [vim](http://www.vim.org/) as follows `sudo vim /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`
2. Search for the line containing `memory_limit` by pressing the `/` (forward slash) key, type the phrase `memory_limit` and press enter.
3. Once on that line go to vim's insert mode by pressing 'ESC' followed by 'i'.
4. Change the value for the `memory_limit` to something higher, e.g. `memory_limit = 1024M` since you already have `512M` for the limit.
5. Save and exit the configuration file by pressing 'ESC' type in 'wq' and then press 'enter'.

If you don't see any changes it could be that you have an **error** in you `php.ini` configuration file. You are always welcome to comment on the answers to get more help.

Comment: Why would this command require 1024M memory limit? That's really really high.

Comment: @Kevin Composer with Drupal 8 is know for an excessive requirement of memory; if you do a quick search you will see a number of issues related to composer being out of memory when working with Drupal. I read somewhere that this is because of how Composer keeps track of dependencies and we all know Drupal has a lot of them.

Comment: I have tried it without a memory limit now (`php -d memory_limit=-1 \`which composer\` require "drupal/bootstrap"`) but the result stays the same, so while it might be a problem with Drupal's mass of dependencies, it seems to be regrettably a fact that I seem to cannot use it with composer.

Comment: Note that composer now (not sure if it used to) sets its own memory limit of 1.5GB.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix this will be to add a swap space to the instance. Please note, this error can appear even if you set memory_limit= -1, as eventually, the system will run out of memory if the maximum memory is limited.

Please note, the commands required to execute varies with the OS variant. One example is below.

Run the following commands:

> sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=2048
>
> sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
>
> sudo chmod 600 /var/swap.1
>
> sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1

To survive a restart, append the following entry to /etc/fstab

```
/var/swap.1   swap    swap    defaults        0   0
```

Comment: I don't see any mention of AWS anywhere in this topic...I doubt this answer will help.

Comment: AWS was just an example. Updated the post anyway to make it clear.